# How to modify a binary while it is running in gdb

Tags: linux, gdb

**Edit: The actual problem is with the method by which the binary is updated and isn't due to an issue with gdb. Please see the answer below for details.**

*Original question:*

Somewhat recently, I can no longer compile a program while gdb is running the program and stopped at a breakpoint. Trying to write to the binary again will result in a "text file busy" error.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit, kernel 4.4.0-75.

I don't think I'm looking for the right thing, as a few searches for "gdb text file busy" or similar isn't yielding any results. The gdb manual specifically mentions this behavior (compile again while running gdb) is supported and indeed I have done this many times previously.

Would appreciate any pointers on what has changed and how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: "while running GDB" is not the same as "while a target process exists".  Have you tried recompiling after terminating the target (but leaving GDB open)?

Comment: And the `gdb` manual specifically talks about it -- "The kill command is also useful if you wish to recompile and relink your program, since on many systems it is impossible to modify an executable file while it is running in a process. In this case, when you next type run, GDB notices that the file has changed, and reads the symbol table again (while trying to preserve your current breakpoint settings)."

Comment: @BenVoigt If I kill the process first or otherwise terminate it, then I am able to write to the binary. The point of this question however is that modifying the binary while it was being run used to work. In this case when I run again gdb reloads the symbols as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Some further searching indicates this excellent post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188041/10847 which explains that the **method by which the binary is updated** is relevant here. In this case, the build system is copying the binary using `cp a b` which will fail. `cp -f a b` will delete b, then overwrite with a, allowing gdb to continue debugging the old binary while the new one is written to disk.

Comment: You should fix the title on your question now that you understand what's going on.

Comment: Good idea @BenVoigt, I've updated the title and added some info to the question as well.